# Some kind of problem in sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find_by(email: user_params[:email])
        if @user && @user.password == user_params[:password]
            cookies[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to blogs_path
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = "invalid email or password"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password)
        end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1> Sign in  </h1>

<%= form_with(url: sessions_path, method: :post) do |form| %>
  <div>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>

  <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I am using Rails and have created a SessionsController with a create action to handle the form submission. However, it seems that the form is not being processed correctly, and I can't figure out why. Whenever i click submit in this it just render the form in the previous way

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and provide some guidance on how to fix it? I would really appreciate any assistance in getting the form submission to work properly..

Comment: Does it render the "invalid email or password" message? Do you really store the user's password in plain text in the DB?

Comment: As @spickermann pointed out, the problem is with the authentication. The error message is not shown because the `flash.now[:notice]` is for remote calls, but this does not seem to be one. Can you try with `flash[:notice]`? Also, do you use the `has_secure_password` option?

Comment: @spickermann yeah i have been following a tutorial in which the person is teaching what  we should not do and one of the thing is not storing password in plain text in database. But i get stuck in the first thing and no it does not render the flash notice and also does not redirect_to blogs_path it just goes into its previous state when the form is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
# add user model v
form_with(model: @user, url: sessions_path, method: :post)
```

This way generated input `name` attributes will be `user[email]` and `user[password]`. Because your `params` must have a user key:  `{user: {email: "myemail", password: "123"}}`, because you're requiring it `params.require(:user)`.

Also, you'll need this for error response to be shown if you have *Turbo*, (which you have by default in rails 7):

```rb
render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

**Update**

When you're making a form the most important part is what `name` attributes are generated by the form builder:

```rb
<%= form_with url: "/sign_in", method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%#=> <input type="text" name="email"> %>
<% end %> #                      ^^^^^

<%= form_with model: @user, url: "/sign_in", method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%#=> <input type="text" name="user[email]"> %>
<% end %> #                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You just have to know how `form_with` works:
*https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with*

Submitting the form takes you to `SessionsController#create`, submitted form parameters are parsed by rails and are available in `params` helper, for url encoded parameters it looks like this:

```rb
#                                   name=value
>> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("email=asdf")
=> {"email"=>"asdf"}
>> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("user[email]=asdf")
=> {"user"=>{"email"=>"asdf"}}
```

By default, `params` returns an [`ActionController::Parameters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) object. You have to permit parameters so you can give them to `User` model. This is not allowed: `User.create(params)` because I can potentially send `email=myemail&superadmin=true` and now I'm in charge.

In your controller, first thing that happens is a call to
`user_params[:email]` => `params.require(:user).permit(:email,:password)`

```
>> parameters = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("email=myemail")
>> params     = ActionController::Parameters.new(parameters)
#  ^ this is what you have
#  v this is what happens (you have to look at server logs)
>> params.require(:user)
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.4.3/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:500:in `require':
param is missing or the value is empty: user (ActionController::ParameterMissing)
```

If you add `model: @user`:

```rb
>> parameters = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("user%5Bemail%5D=myemail")
>> params     = ActionController::Parameters.new(parameters)
>> params.require(:user)
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"myemail"} permitted: false>
>> params.require(:user).permit(:email)
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"myemail"} permitted: true>
#                                                                 ^
# everything else should work from this point
```

Note, that you don't have to permit params when you're fetching individual attributes, as in `User.find(params[:id])`.

How did i determine this? Look at the form, see no `model: @user` which means all of that ^ above. It's a common issue. But all you have to do is look at the logs, you can see *PARAMETERS* there and any errors that don't show up in the browser.

Comment: hey man thanks for the answer but can u help me understand why was this happening like little bit more in detail. And also how did u determine that this is the actual mistake even chatgpt can't pinpoint what's happening.